# How to use JavaScript Flow Version Language with WebStorm and React JSX?

Tags: javascript, react-native, webstorm

I couldn't setup Flow in WebStorm using react-native.

[image]

I already tried to add libraries for types:

[image]

[image]

Also, I tried to install flow-typed. But still, the IDE cannot resolve symbols when I choose Flow as JS language.

Also tried to invalidate cache and restart the WebStorm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I cleaned `Flow package or executable`

[image]

2. Invalidate cache and restart again.
3. Selected `<myproject>/node_modules/flow-bin` on `Flow package or executable` again.
4. Erased and re-typed `@flow` annotation.